# MVC: Handle Authentication Timeouts through Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

So we have had some issues were users were getting an error when attempting to perform actions on a website, we believe this may be a result of users logins timing out/becoming expired.

I was wondering if there is a way to override what the ajax call is attempting and redirect to a login page?

Im hoping that we wont have to go into every ajax call in the site and add something like if(response.notLoggedIn) and do a redirect from the view.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So I was wrong in thinking you can't return a whole view in an ajax call to abort what was happening.

In the authentication controller I had this.
Note: if a request comes from an expired connection it will always end up here.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            TempData["toastrMessage"] = "Your session has expired.";
            TempData["toastrType"] = "Error";
            return View("LoginReload");
        }
```

No errors get retuned from the ajax call and the page just goes directly to the login page.